# What’s the word for the recount of events used to solve a mystery?

Tags: single-word-requests

I believe there is a certain word used to describe the recount or unraveling of information to solve a mystery. Typically, in murder-mystery movies, towards the end - the climax of the movie - the actor will give a monologue describing in detail, “How it was done”. What is the word used to describe that monologue. It’s very specific but I can’t think of it! Thanks

Comment: It's flagged as a duplicate but I'm not sure the duplicate is the same thing, at least when discussing pop culture: the older question is about what TV Tropes calls the Motive Rant or Evil Gloating, commonly done by the villain, whereas this is what TV Tropes calls The Summation, done by the detective. https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/MotiveRant https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EvilGloating https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/TheSummation

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to EL&U, Casper. I think the word you're looking for is [denouement](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/denouement).

The Cambridge online defines this as:

> the end of a story, in which everything is explained, or the end result of a situation

In murder mystery stories the *denouement* usually takes the form you describe, in other types of fiction, and in some factual presentations, there are other forms of denouement but the detective explaining it all and revealing one of his or her listeners as the culprit is the classic denouement of murder mysteries. Conan Doyle, Agatha Christie and the script writers of Death in Paradise all use it.

Comment: The *denouement* refers to the [sequence of] events themselves. But OP asks for *the word for the **recount** of [those events]*, which is the generally called the ***reveal***.